# Android: How to change textview of another application

Tags: android, textview, android-activity, android-service

I have to different applications. First application has background service. Second application has activity with textview.
Question: how can I detect second app launch using service from first app? And how to change textview's text from service?

Thanks.

Comment: Applications are bound through windowtokens, these can't be used from other applications, a workaround is throwing an intent in the background service and catch it in the second application through a broadcastreceiver, pass the text you want to change in the intent through a bundle

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect the launch on an other application, neither you can change the TextView of a different application directly.

But you can achieve this with cooperation. The second application could notify the Service about being started, and the Service could ask the First Activity to change its TextView.

This can be achieved with intents. The Activity in the first application could start the Service as it starts, and the Service can send a broadcast or send an intent to the activity directly to request it to modify its TextView.

If you want to notify the Activity only when it runs, and don't want to wake it up like in the previous example, then I suggest you to read [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) about bound services. It gives you a complete example on how to bind to a service, and also describes how to make requests back to the Activity.

> Notice that this example does not show how the service can respond to
>   the client. If you want the service to respond, then you need to also
>   create a Messenger in the client. Then when the client receives the
>   onServiceConnected() callback, it sends a Message to the service that
>   includes the client's Messenger in the replyTo parameter of the send()
>   method.

Answer (score 0):

use broadcastreceiver in the that update your another application.
if you are using service then it will not update your GUI of another application.
broadcastreceiver is the best practice to do which you want.